# C# exception and wrong formatting in Console output after changing Streamread path to resource file

Tags: c#, console, resources, streamreader

First im sory for the bad english and this is my first question here. pls excuse if im doing something wrong.

Im reading data from a textfile using the streamreader. now I made the file a resource and the output formatting has changed.

Reading the textfile before:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("WordFinder.Data");
var resourceName = "WordFinder.Data.Data.WordsDictionaryFinalUppercase-de-DE.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
   for (string currentWord = reader.ReadLine(); currentWord != null; currentWord = reader.ReadLine())
   {...
```

output method:

```
internal static void PrintWordList(IEnumerable<string> wordList, out int printedWordsCount)
{
     printedWordsCount = 0;
     foreach (var word in wordList)
     {
           printedWordsCount++;
           Console.Write("{0,-40}", word);
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output is as expected:

Word1                Word2                 Word3

now I change the path for the streamreader to resource:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Data.Properties.Resources.Dict_de))
{
    for (string currentWord = reader.ReadLine(); currentWord != null; currentWord = reader.ReadLine()
{....
```

output:

Word1

Word2

Word3

an a exception is thrown for ashort moment but the app continues running.

Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: It would be really useful if you tell us the exception type and message. I suppose that `Data.Properties.Resources.Dict_de` is a string containing the content of the text file, but in this context is interpreted by the StreamReader constructor as URL or file name.

Comment: I think I got the problem. The **Data.Properties.Resources.Dict_de** contains the whole content of the file and not the path to it. But how can I read the file line by line using the streamreader:

Comment: Convert the string to a byte array using `Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes`, then create a `MemoryStream` on top of the byte array. Or - much simpler - use `String.Split` to split the string into lines.